# Custom Chatter Actions Being Invoked on Page Load?

Tags: visualforce

I am implementing Chatter Custom Actions, but seeing some strange behavior I am trying to avoid/better understand...

Below is a simple example that reproduces the issue. If you add a detail button to Contact for the page below, it works fine. If the Contact doesn't have a cellphone, it will return you to the detail page using the JS script at the bottom of the page.

But if you add this as a custom chatter action (i.e. an action that invokes the VF page), the contact detail page continually refreshes as soon as you load the detail page. Maybe this is my not understanding Chatter Actions enough, but why would the code for a VF page for a Chatter Action be invoked without me ever actually invoking the action? I've also seen the same thing happen if you add an action to a VF page and use that with an action.

And in case you are wondering - why does there have to be that JS script at all? By all accounts, that is the only way to return the user to the detail screen once the custom chatter action has been completed...

```
public class ChatterError {

public Boolean bshowsent {get;set;}
private final Contact contact;

    public ChatterError (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.contact = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();

        if (String.IsEmpty(Contact.MobilePhone)) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'There is no Cell Phone Listed for this Contact!'));
                bshowsent = TRUE;
            }
    }

}
```

And the page

```
<apex:page StandardController="Contact" extensions="ChatterError">

<apex:pageMessages/>

<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MobilePhone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel id="smssentpanel">

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!bshowsent}">
<script>
          window.top.location='https://na1.salesforce.com/{!contact.id}';
</script>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```